# Un anuncio de "admob" hace request pero no "impress"

Tags: android, firebase, ios, flutter, admob

He desarrollado una app en Flutter tanto para IOS como para Android. En Android todo funciona bien, los anuncios hacen "request" e "impress" bien, es decir, se muestran como deberían. Sin embargo, en IOS los anuncios mandan la "request" pero en ningún momento se llegan a mostrar y no sé por qué. En el emulador del ordenador salían anuncios como "Test Device".

Subí la aplicación hace solo 2 días, puede ser que sea por eso porque además al intentar añadirla a admob desde la AppStore no me aparece listada.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Hola, es importante agregar el código para saber que realizas, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Es un código muy extenso, no he puesto nada por que no sé exactamente qué parte poner.

Answer (score 0):

no indicaste que tipos de anuncios estabas cargando en tu aplicación, pero, te doy algunos tips.

1. Siempre los primeros despligues demoran un rato en conectar con la red de anuncios de Admob, puede tomar un par de semanas hasta que Google empiece a enviar anuncios a tus aplicaciones.
2. en iOS podrías agregar el identificador de publicidad antes de compilar.
3. Verifica que los identificadores de tus anuncios sean los correctos.